# Kendo Scheduler additional button in custom edit popup template

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-scheduler

I have a simple Kendo Scheduler Demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/IqIYI/7

In this demo I have a custom edit template defined as follows:

```
<script id="editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
   <h3>Edit meeting</h3>
   <p>
       <label>Title: <input name="title" /></label>
   </p>
   <p>
       <label>Start: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="start" /></label>
   </p>
   <p>
       <label>End: <input data-role="datetimepicker" name="end" /></label>
   </p>
</script>
```

This template has 2 buttons in create-new-mode and 3 buttons when in edit-mode by default.

I am now trying to add a 4th button to the edit popup and then catch its click event and do something else (create a new popup filled with the one of the event - functionality of "edit as new").

I am adding this button through the edit event of kendo in the case of an edit of an actual event (fired whenever the popup template loads).

```
  edit: function(e) {
            if (!e.event.isNew()) {
                $(".k-edit-buttons.k-state-default").prepend('<a class="k-button" id="editasnew">Edit as New</a>');
          }
  },
```

The button has an id="editasnew", and then a click event catcher:

```
  $('#editasnew').click(function(){
    console.log("edit now");
    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    scheduler.cancelEvent();

    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log("add new event now");
      scheduler.addEvent({ title: "(No title)" });
    }, 2000);
  });
```

But! the click event is never fired.

So I wonder, is there a way to add the button a different way? (parameters through a kendo function - i did not find that in the documentation)

..or maybe restructure the click event catcher (maybe clicking this button has some stoppropagation function given by kendo)?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

The click event needs to specially added (I am not sure why), but this works:

1. Wrap the click handler inside a function

_

```
function addClickEvent(){
    $('#editasnew').click(function(){
      console.log("edit now");
      var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
      scheduler.cancelEvent();

      setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("add new event now");
        scheduler.addEvent({ title: "(No title)" });
      }, 2000);

    });
  }
```

2. Execute above function in the edit event of the scheduler

_

```
  edit: function(e) {
            if (!e.event.isNew()) {
                $(".k-edit-buttons.k-state-default").prepend('<a class="k-button" id="editasnew">Edit as New</a>');
          addClickEvent();
          }
  },
```

For anyone interested here is my updated example:

http://dojo.telerik.com/IqIYI/21

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use columns.command.click Function

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { command: [ {
        name: "details",
        click: function(e) {
          // e.target is the DOM element representing the button
          var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr"); // get the current table row (tr)
          // get the data bound to the current table row
          var data = this.dataItem(tr);
          console.log("Details for: " + data.name);
        }
      } ]
   }
  ],
  dataSource: [ { name: "Jane Doe" } ]
});
```

Comment: I do not see a way to implement this because the kendo "grid" is a different tool than the one I have a question about - kendo "scheduler".

Comment: Sorry I do not know sheduler